# Compute the integral?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $a>b>0$, compute

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^b-x^a}{\ln x} dx$$

I tried to use substiution $t=\ln x$, but it didn't simplify the computation. Thank in advance.

Comment: Could you come up with a more descriptive title please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Feynman said that I have to define an integral like this $$f(p) =\int_0^1 \frac{x^p - 1}{\ln x}dx,\quad\quad\quad p > -1$$
then do what he always do: $$f'(p) = \int_0^1 x^p dx = \frac{1}{p + 1}$$
with the condition $f(0) = 0$, I got that $$f(p) = \ln(p + 1).$$

Then your integral is equal to $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^b - 1 - (x^a - 1)}{\ln x}dx = \int_0^1\frac{x^b - 1}{\ln x}dx - \int_0^1 \frac{x^a - 1}{\ln x}dx = \ln(b + 1) - \ln(a +1) =\ln \frac{b + 1}{a + 1}$$

Hey it works! Thank you Mr. Feynman!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Consider
$$\int_0^1\int_a^b x^t dt\,dx=\int_a^b\int_0^1 x^t dx\,dt.$$

> $$\log\frac{b+1}{a+1}.$$

Comment: Why your final answer (in the spoiler hint) is $\log \frac{b}{a}$? For example, [this is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+%28x%5E2+-+x%5E1%29%2F+lnx+) not $\log(2/1)$

Comment: @Azlif: my bad, fixed. You can check the integrals straight away.